# MySQL Query to calculate Previous Week

Tags: mysql

I would like to calculate my total order amount in the previous week.

I got the query for getting the data for the last 7 days from the current date.

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount  FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day);
```

Now how can I get Previous week data only, excluding this week.

For e.g. This week I made $15,000 and last week i made $14,000.

I get the $15,000 by running the above query.

But i dont know how to calculate previous week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the additional information you gave in Alex's answer, I guess the following may work:

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount, "Previous week" AS Week FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
AND order_placed_date < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)
UNION
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount, "This week" AS Week FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)
```

This should return two rows and two columns, with a total amount for each of the weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Previous 8 to 14 days records excluding the last 7 days records, query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` 
WHERE `Field_Name` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
AND `Field_Name` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

- `Field_Name` : Must be valid date in format of `YYYY-mm-dd` (2012-09-20).
- `Table_Name` : From where you need to fetch records.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "rolling weeks" (sliding 7-days-long windows) instead of weeks starting on Sunday (or other specific weekdays),

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date BETWEEN
 date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) AND
 date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 8 day);
```

Comment: This is also useful. But I would like to track from today to last 7 days ( For this week), and from the last 7 days to further 7 days for the previous week.

Comment: You mean, you want weeks to overlap by one day? Or are you implying `excluded` in either the "to" or "from" parts of your sentence? BETWEEN does `included` so it needs care.

Comment: I want to calculate Last week starting from todays date and going back. I dont need weeks such as 1st to 7th and so .

Comment: ...and the query I supply does exactly what you say you want (so does Alistair's, using < and >= instead of BETWEEN).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(goods_total) AS Total_Amount  FROM orders
WHERE order_placed_date >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
AND order_placed_date < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following query:

```
SELECT   count(order_placed_date) 
FROM     orders
WHERE    YEARWEEK(order_placed_date) = YEARWEEK(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: I suspect you need a date_sub like YEARWEEK(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY))

Comment: My above version works fine, your version also works but by removing " - " and replacing it withe a comma " , " --------------
YEARWEEK(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(current_date)+8 DAY) last_sunday
, YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(current_date)+8 DAY)) last_week_of_year
, DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(current_date)+1 DAY) this_sunday
, YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(current_date)+1 DAY)) this_week_of_year;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
      last_sunday: 2012-01-29
last_week_of_year: 201205
      this_sunday: 2012-02-05
this_week_of_year: 201206
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [mysql Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

WEEKOFYEAR()